# Gatsby WhereInput query compiles with errors

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a GraphQL query which I can run perfectly using GraphQL playground.

However, when I put it within Gatsby page it throws an error and gives no further diagnostic.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    cms {
      headerActions: callToActions(
        where: { placement: Header, AND: { pages_some: { path: $path } } }
      ) {
        url
        label
      }
    }
  }
`
```

The Error:

```
error GraphQL Error Expected a value matching type `[CMS_CallToActionWhereInput!]`, but got an object value
```

I'm puzzled which direction to even dig as Gatsby gives no error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it expecting an **Array** but I don't see any array in your `calToAction` Query, I guess this might fix your problem:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    cms {
      headerActions: callToActions(
        where: [ { placement: Header, AND: { pages_some: { path: $path } } } ]
      ) {
        url
        label
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Okay, figured it out with your help:
     where: { placement: Header, AND: [{ pages_some: { path: $path } }] }
Then simplied it to 
    where: { placement: Header, pages_some: { path: $path } }

Thanks!